# Strings maintaining leading and trailing quotes from JSON when using Jerkson

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0, jackson, jerkson

JSON in question:

```
{
"search_id": "",
"type": "Search.filter",
"query": "bar,club",
"params": {
    "search_id": "",
    "user_id": "",
    "client": "ios",
    "lat": 40.73199375351,
    "lon": -74.00080404533901,
    "radius": 20
}
```

}

Code to Retrieve the Data:

```
val json = Json.parse(new String(body))
println((json \ "search_id") + " | " + (json \ "query"))
println(json)
```

printing just the json JsValue prints out the entire JSON as expected. printing out the first item produces: "" | "bar,club"

Why is it maintaining the quotes from JSON formatting? That's not part of the string, it's basically saying that the content inside the quotes is a string. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJson), you should call `.as[sometype]` (unsafe conversion) or `asOpt[sometype]` (safe).

```
println((json \ "search_id").as[String] + " | " + (json \ "query").as[String])
```